# Was the first US government-issued pilot license issued in 1927 or '28?

Tags: aviation-history, faa, pilot-certification

[image: The first US pilot license]

The top image says it was issued April 6, 1928, while the bottom one says April 6, 1927. Are these two different documents issued a year apart, or is there a discrepancy?

Comment: Your photos say issued in '27, expires in '28.  What's the question here?

Comment: @RalphJ I didn't see that it said "expires." Not sure why I didn't notice that.

Comment: His Navy call sign would probably have been "Phil"...

Comment: As a note, even in 1946 (maybe later also) there were "Airman" identification cards with a picture of the Airman that were separate from the Pilot's Certificate.

Comment: @MichaelHall   <<< Groan! >>>

Comment: @MichaelHall what is the significance of the call sign "Phil"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The top picture is the actual Private Pilot "license" that "expires" on April 6, 1928.  The bottom picture is a "Pilot's Identification Card" that was "issued" on April 6, 1927, without an expiration date, and accompanies the Private Pilot license.

It appears that the Pilot's Identification Card and the actual Private Pilot license were issued as a pair at the same time.

[image]

*(highlighting is mine, picture source is from the OP's question)*

Comment: *facepalm* I'm not sure how I missed that it says "expires." Thank you!

Comment: @Someone No worries.  I often do a quick read and miss something that otherwise might seem obvious.  I just enhanced my answer for others who might be interested in learning about early types of necessary pilot documents.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wiki...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_licensing_and_certification

Aero-Club de France began issuing certificates in 1910, retroactive to 1909. Bleriot, Wright Bros are some notables.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pilots_awarded_an_Aviator%27s_Certificate_by_the_A%C3%A9ro-Club_de_France_in_1909

Royal Aero Club (UK) also 1910.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Aero_Club

Aero Club of America began issuing licenses in 1911. Glenn Curtiss and the Wright Bros, among others.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aero_Club_of_America

It seems these were mostly ceremonial, rather than required.